# Logging dropwizard-metrics with log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, metrics

I develop a backend app with multiple webserivces and I would like to log some metrics about execution time, amount of calls etc., gathered with [dropwizard-metrics](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/). I would want to log them using log4j.

I know there are some built-in reporters and some 3rd party ones, but I don't see (surprisingly) any log4j reporter, so I wanted to make my own. I would want to log metrics let's say every hour, then at the end of the day reset the metrics and reroll the log file (maybe log the last metrics right before rerolling).

Problem is that I want new metrics to overwrite metrics from the previous hour if they are from the same day. Let's say a single metric log takes 50 lines of text. I want to have the same amount of lines at 1:00 hour and 22 hours later (that is 50 lines), so when someone opens the metrics log he can see the most recent metrics immediately instead of scrolling to the bottom.

Is there any option in log4j/log4j-extras to signal it to clear a file before the next log call or something like that? I could manually clear my file 'the java way', but I don't think it's a good idea to 'fight' with log4j, could potentially break something.

Seems like a silly problem, but I would like to have good user experience with those metrics, and I don't need to have the info from every hour, even if some metrics are lost, because of the restart or something. Any log4j tricks are appreciated, or maybe a link to a custom log4j reporter for dropwizard-metrics, I couldn't find any and it seems surprising to me since log4j is so popular.